# 2sxc - Time field editor with seconds

Tags: 2sxc

Where to start if I need time field similar to DateTime "show Time picker",
but I also need seconds. If is posible to also hide date part it would be exactly what I need.

Comment: This is not a built-in feature, you would have to create a custom input-field, check out http://2sxc.org/en/Blog/post/custom-input-type-advanced-dynamic-data

Comment: @iJungleBoy I accepted this as a solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accepted comment from iJungleBoy as solution,

even if I didn't create it yet.

When I become good enough to make it I will post it back.